# Toggle jQuery function on and off

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

I am new to jQuery and am having some trouble figuring something out.

I have this function that is called at the bottom of the page to attach an auto-complete feature to a text box, this part is working fine. Here is the code that is called to enable the auto-complete:

```
$(function(){
    $('#intext').autocomplete('get-data.php?mode=sql', {
        width: 400,
        max: 5,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

However the search box contains two radio buttons for two different types of searches. The auto-complete feature should only be available for one type of search.

So my question is, how can I enable this by clicking one radio button, and disable it by clicking the second radio button?

EDIT

The auto-complete script has a .autocomplete( "disable" ) method, but I don't know how to enable/disable that based on which radio button is checked.

EDIT 2

I am trying to get the method suggested by "Rory McCrossan" to work, as I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete. Here's the code for my radio buttons and search box:

```
News: <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="search_type" value="news" checked="checked" onclick="this.form.action='/search.php';" />
Media Gallery: <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="search_type" value="media" onclick="this.form.action='/media.php';" />
<input id="intext" class="txt" type="text" name="searchterms" />
```

I have the following code in the script that runs on each page:

```
addAutoComplete($("#intext"));

$(".myRadio").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "news") {
        if (!$("#intext").hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input"))
            addAutoComplete($("#intext"));
    }
    else {
        $("#intext").autocomplete('destroy')
    }
});


function addAutoComplete($el) {
    $('#intext').autocomplete('autocomplete-data.php?mode=sql', {
        width: 400,
        max: 5,
        selectFirst: false
    });

}
```

This does not seem to work, and the Error Console in Firefox doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the jQueryUI autocomplete, you can use `$el.autocomplete("destroy")` to remove the autocomplete function.

```
addAutoComplete($("#intext")); // on load

$(".myRadio").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "a") {
        if (!$("#intext").hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input"))
            addAutoComplete($("#intext"));
    }
    else {
        $("#intext").autocomplete('destroy')
    }
});

function addAutoComplete($el) { 
    $el.autocomplete('get-data.php?mode=sql', {
        width: 400,
        max: 5,
        selectFirst: false
    });
}
```

Comment: By having "#myRadio" doesn't that mean that both radio buttons would need the same ID? I am also trying to write code that validates and elements cannot have the same ID. I am new to jQuery as well, so if my understanding is incorrect please feel free to step in and correct me.

Comment: It's a `.` which is a class selector.

Comment: Sorry, got a couple of different things mixed up when I looked it over. I will give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I've just added a slight update to check that the input doesn't already have `autocomplete` added to it, before adding it again.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Will update my question with some additional info in a minute.

Comment: wouldn't this `change` will be called twice each time a different radio is clicked?

Comment: I've updated my question to include what I have tried so far.

Comment: @TejasvaDhyani no, it's only called once for each element that changes. Using `change` instead of `click` has the benefit that people using keyboard input to change options will still fire the events.

Comment: I've tested the code and it would appear to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrcrn/1/ Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Trying that out now to see what's up.

Comment: No errors in the console. Your demo works, but mine does not. I get an alert saying "adding autocomplete" when the page first loads, but nothing happens when I click the radio buttons. I'm playing with it still.

Comment: The "change" function isn't even called when the radio buttons are clicked.

Comment: I think it is. Here's the exact code for the radio buttons: <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="search_type" value="news" checked="checked" onclick="this.form.action='http://domain.com/search.php';document.searchform.level.value='';" />  Media Gallery: <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="search_type" value="media" onclick="this.form.action='http://domain.com/media.php';document.searchform.level.value='search';" />

Comment: The formatting is a bit messed up here, the onclick events are not showing up right, although they are correct and working. But the class names match what is in your code.

Comment: `<input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="search_type" value="news" checked="checked" onclick="this.form.action='http://domain.com/search.php';document.searchform.level.value='';" />  Media Gallery: <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="search_type" value="media" onclick="this.form.action='http://domain.com/media.php';document.searchform.level.value='search';" />`

Comment: I think I figured it out, just trying it out now.

Comment: Your code did work fine. It is because of where it was being placed on the page. I just added the code to the script that was already there calling the auto-complete. However, when I moved that to the bottom of the page it all worked fine. I assumed that if the auto-complete worked with the original code in that location this code would work there as well, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to disable the autocomplete when one of the two radiobuttons is selected. You call a jQuery UI method by giving the methodname as the first parameter to the jQuery plugin call. So for example:"

```
// First create the autocomplete
$('#textbox1').autocomplete();

// call a method on the 'autocompleted' textbox
$('#textbox1').autocomplete('methodname', 'methodparam1', methodparam2, etc)
```

So in this case:

```
$('.classOfTheTwoRadioButtons').change(function(e) {
  var method = $(e.target).is(':checked [value=valueIfAutocomplete]')? 'enable': 'disable';
  $('#textbox').autocomplete(method);
});
```

Other option: Create two textboxes with the same name and only attach the autocomplete on one of them. Use the `toggle()` function of jquery to hide the one you do not want to see when the selected radiobutton is checked.

```
$('.classOfTheTwoRadioButtons').change(function(e) {
  var $e = $(e.target);
  $('#firstTextBox').toggle($e.val() === 'value1');
  $('#secondTextBox').toggle($e.val() === 'value2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you `autocomplete()` plugin has a `destroy` action of some kind that removes his behavior. If so, just call it when your "autocomplete off" radio is selected.

If your plugin doesn't have that option, just create to text fields. The first one with attached autocomplete, the second without it. Then toggle them based on your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

given that radio button with value 'a' enables the autocomplete and the one with value 'b' disables it

```
$(".myRadio[value='a']").click(function() {
    $('#intext').autocomplete('enable');
}
$(".myRadio[value='b']").click(function() {
    $('#intext').autocomplete('disable');
}
```

Comment: I changed the values in the code you posted to the actual values used in my form, but clicking the second radio button doesn't disable the auto-complete.

Comment: I tried adding some alerts to your script just to try it, and the functions are not called at all when the radio buttons are clicked.